# How to get shadows information in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, shadows, npr

I have a WIP looking like this

[image]

Now I want to do something about a background and I want to do it in a similar halftone style. But when I'm applying it the same way as I did on the models, the dots are covering the shadow.

I need a shadow information, to influence them somehow, but I have no idea how to extract it. I'm using Cycles.

Comment: Please read your question and try to imagine you are trying to understand it without knowing your situation. What do you want to do about the background? What are you applying where, how? What dots are covering what shadows and how? What does it mean? How does it differ from what you expect? Please be specific. Telling about your shader setup would be good, showing node screenshots - even better. Sharing a .blend file as an example could be a good idea.

Comment: Hard to understand what you want. Maybe this can be done in the compositor using the shadow pass, but I'm terrible at guessing.

Comment: As I understand it, you would like to put the shading of a surface through a half-tone screen during the render? Possibly in Object or UV space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so  I achieved the result I wanted. Unfortunately, it's not fully procedural. What I needed to do was to bake shadow map of the plane and than I could use this information to make a final artwork.

Comment: With EEVEE, you might be able to do it in one pass using the _Shader to RGB_ node, allowing you to feed the response of a surface to light back into the tree, ( for example to multiply with a halftone screen ). I've not done it with EEVEE yet, but did it quite a lot with Blender Internal. That is not possible with a path-tracer, working the way Cycles does.